# How can I get Hours only that was inputted on my textbox and multiply with keyup input in rateperhour then display the answer in my total?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

[image: This is my running website]

Good day! I have a problem on how can I get Hours that was inputted on textbox and multiple with another textbox named as rateperhour and trigger the total when rateperhour changed. Thank you who will willing to help. I appreciate it so much. Thank you so much!

```
<script>
   $(function () { //calculate total OT

        $("#ratePerHour").keyup(function (e) {


            var ratePerHour = $("#ratePerHour").val();
            var endTime = $("#endTime").val;
            var OT = new Date(endTime).getHours();
            var result = "";

            if (ratePerHour !== "" && endTime !== "" && $.isNumeric(ratePerHour) && $.isNumeric(endTime)) {
                result = parseFloat(ratePerHour) * parseFloat(OT);
            }
            $("#otTotal").val(result);

        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply get hours using `split(':')[0]` which will split your hh:mm:ss in array and using `[0]` will give you hours value and then use this to calculate total.

Demo Code :

```js
$(function() { //calculate total OT

  $("#ratePerHour").keyup(function(e) {
    var ratePerHour = $("#ratePerHour").val();
  
    var time1 = $("#endTime").val().split(':')[0];//get hours
   var OT =parseInt(time1, 10)//parse it 
    var result = "";
    if ((ratePerHour != "" && time1 != "") && ($.isNumeric(ratePerHour) && $.isNumeric(time1))) {
      result = parseFloat(ratePerHour) * parseFloat(OT);
    }
    $("#otTotal").val(result);
  console.log("Rate -- "+ratePerHour+" * "+OT+" = "+result)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
ratePerHour :<input type="text" id="ratePerHour"> <br>
endTime : 
<input  type="time" step="1" id="endTime">
Total : <input type="text" id="otTotal">
```